# Would time dilation be too great for the early universe to expand?

Tags: general-relativity, time, big-bang

I read that one second after the big bang the universe was composed of photons electrons and neutrinos. Wouldn't the density of energy/matter have caused such extreme time dilation that the universe would never expand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time dilation only applies between distant observers.  Local observers always say that time goes normally around THEM.  It's only when separated observers compare each other that you get a problem.  So, not, there is no contradiction in having an observer in an arbitrarily dense area say that his local neighborhood is expanding.

Comment: How about for an observer of the big bang?

Comment: @user36093: there are two senses in which to answer this question.  The first is that the big bang is a singularity, so any questions about the big bang itself are outside the realm of applicability of classical general relativity -- every quntity is infinite there, so doing physics there doesn't mean anything.  The second answer is to note that every observer in a Robertson-Walker spacetime has the big bang in their past, so in a sense, all of us are observers of the big bang.

Comment: nice answer, thanks, but is it assumed that gravity was not active shortly after the big bang? Because otherwise, surely if you have gravity you have GR

Comment: @user36093: yes, of course you have GR, but there's a certain point where the matter density becomes large enough that QFT effects become as significant as the effects of classical GR, and you need a theory which includes both GR and QFT as limits, and this theory has not been rigorously proven to exist.